# Is this kind of table relationships allowed in mysql and cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using mysql and cakephp 2.5

I have 3 tables.

- TableA has a one-to-many relationship to TableC. TableB has a one-to-many relationship to TableC.
- I want to delete rows from parent TableB without deleting the associated child rows in TableC.

Can the above 2 conditions be done in cakephp and mysql? If yes, what are the things to configure for these conditions?

Comment: Yes, you can delete rows from any table you want without deleting tables from another table.  I doubt that's really what you're asking.  Please try to be more specific in your question with examples of what you've tried, what problems you're having...etc.

Comment: _What you can do_ versus _What you should do_ are two different discussions. It sounds as though there can be referential integrity between one row within TableC and both TableA and TableB. In that case, you should NOT delete from TableB if you break referential integrity. You should add sample data to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default cakephp does not delete associated rows when deleting a record. You can set this with the dependent parameter.

So if you want dependent records from tableC to be deleted when a record from tableA is delete, you should set up your relation like this:

```
class ModelA extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ModelC' => array(
            'dependent' => true
        )
    );
}
```

And for ModelB which should not delete rows from tableC when a row from tableB is deleted:

```
class ModelB extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'ModelC'
    );
}
```

I think this is what you needed?